# Java Smartheets - Column ID is not created when creating new Sheet

Tags: smartsheet-api-2.0

1. The following code

   Sheet aSheet = new Sheet();
   List columns = new ArrayList<>();
   Column claim_number = new Column().setTitle("EMS Claim Number");
   claim_number.setType(ColumnType.TEXT_NUMBER);
   claim_number.setPrimary(Boolean.TRUE);
   claim_number.setId(4583173393803100L);
   columns.add(claim_number);
   aSheet.setColumns(columns);
   aSheet.setName("Name");
   Sheet created = smartsheet.sheetResources().createSheet(aSheet);

Results in the error

```
  "message" : "The columnId 4583173393803100 is invalid."
```

SmartSheets gives an example of a [columnID](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#cells) so I tried to use numbers of the same number of digits

2. If I create the columns without an ID and then later try to populate rows in the new sheet

   ```
   Row row = new Row.AddRowBuilder().setCells(cells).setToBottom(true).build();
   smartsheet.sheetResources().rowResources().addRows(created.getId(), Arrays.asList(row));
   ```

I get the error that the column id are null

```
"message" : "Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: cell.columnId.",
```

**Maven:**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.smartsheet</groupId>
            <artifactId>smartsheet-sdk-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.101.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Questions:**

1. How do I create and set a valid column ID?
2. Why does the API or smartsheet system not autogenerate the column ID and if is does how do I access those values?

Regards
Conteh

Comment: Note that I just has a bug in the code I neglected to getColumns() from the newly created sheet Suggest this is deleted

Answer (score 1):

`columnId` is read only (generated by the Smartsheet API) and should be null in your request to create a sheet.